# Pushing/Apending API response to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to create an array of urls, the array is called "sentences". So far I have seen that you must use a useState if you want to put the API response in an array. This is what I have tried so far.

```
  const [sentences, setSentences] = useState([]);

  const getOpenAIResponse = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      openai.createImage({
        prompt: prompts[i],
        n: 1,
        size: "256x256",
      }).then((response) => {
        setSentences(response.data.data[0].url)
        console.log(sentences)
      })
    }
  };
```

The issue is sentences just refreshes with the next url response that is generated. Using setSentences.push(...) does not work. Is there anything you would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New notes

It looks like I didn't take into account that, when `getOpenAIResponse` runs, you call `openai.createImage` 6 times, and each time that runs you get a URL that needs to be added to `sentences`. Here's some updated code that should work for you:

```js
const getOpenAIResponse = () => {
  imagePromises = [];

  // Collect all image promises in an array
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    imagePromises.push(
      openai.createImage({
        prompt: prompts[i],
        n: 1,
        size: "256x256",
      })
    );
  }

  // Do something once all promises resolve
  Promise.all(imagePromises)
    .then((responses) => {
      setSentences([
        // Keep current list of sentences
        ...sentences,

        // Add new sentences to old list of sentences
        ...responses.map(response => response.data.data[0].url),
      ]);
    });
};
```

#### Old notes

Where you have `setSentences(response.data.data[0].url)`, this is only going to replace your existing ARRAY of sentences with one specific sentence returned by `openai.createImage`. What you want, is you want to take the returned URL, add it to your `sentences` array, then update the state.

To do this, replace your `setSentences` line with `setSentences(sentences.concat(response.data.data[0].url))`

I don't see how you were using `.push` before, but `.push` doesn't "return" the updated array, `.concat` does!

You can see this at work in the Chrome developer console with these two tests:

```js
// This returns 4 which is the size of the array!
[1,2,3].push(4);

// These return [1,2,3,4] which is the new array, with the added new element at the end
[1,2,3].concat(4);
[1,2,3].concat([4]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the argument be wrapped in an array?

Comment: @CherryDT not needed, if you're only appending 1 element to the `sentences` array, you don't need to wrap `response.data.data[0].url` in an array

Comment: It will behave unexpectedly if that element itself is an array though, so it's best to learn it consistently from the start to avoid future surprises. Alternatively I'd recommend the (arguably cleaner) `[...sentences, response.data.data[0].url]` syntax.

Comment: @CherryDT Are you sure it'll behave unexpectedly? If I do `[1,2].concat([3])` I don't see the new array as `[1,2,[3]]`, I see `[1,2,3]`

Comment: That's exactly what's unexpected about it. If you learn "`a.concat(x)` will append `x` to the array", you will be surprised about the case you just showed, where `x` would have been `[3]` and not `3`, yet what was added to the array was `3`. I'm a fan of clearly-defined universal tools to learn where you won't have to keep in mind edge cases later on (an example of a similar issue would be `new Array(...)` where passing a single argument which happens to be a number will lead to entirely different behavior than all other cases - and that's even the reason why it was deprecated). My two cents.

Comment: Aah now i see what you mean @CherryDT - I guess I'm used to it so it's not "unexpected" anymore, but it can be nice, as you mentioned, to make the code very explicit so you know dealing with `x` vs `[x]` has different behavior. In this exact case though, I think the situation is clear enough in both solutions that the new URL will be added to the array - if `.url` starts being an array of URLs, it should be renamed `.urls` to indicate that

Comment: Thank you. For some reason the same problem is persisting. Sentence[0] changes 6 times, and once I click the button that activates the API response again I get Sentence[1] which also regenerates 6 times. It doesn't seem to give me an array of urls as I want.

Comment: @ati Ok so when you click a button, that calls `getOpenAIResponse` right? It looks like the problem we haven't addressed is that you're running `openai.createImage` 6 times for each button click, and each time you expect 6 new URLs to come back and be added to `sentences`, is that correct?

Comment: @ati take a look at the updated answer, I accounted for the fact that you have multiple promises that all need to be resolved before adding the resulting sentences to the array state!

Comment: Hm but now I believe you _really_ need an array in your last answer :) Right? Because `setSentences` should have only one argument, the new value, not multiple. So it should be `setSentences([...sentences, ...newStuff])`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and I get a the letter h for sentences[0], and then 6 image errors.@BlunderingPhilosopher  @cherryDT

Comment: @CherryDT looks like you're a pro QAer  I swear I added that (don't look at the edit history of this answer ) - also Ati - this should now work - sorry for the little typo

Comment: @ati just so you know, I'm just guessing that `response.data.data[0].url` is the correct way to get the image URL from your api response - you may want to triple check that that's accurate :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread operator to add the new url to the array.

```
setSentences([...sentences, response.data.data[0].url])
```

You can also use the concat method to add the new url to the array.

```
setSentences(sentences.concat(response.data.data[0].url))
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason the same problem is persisting. sentences[0] changes 6 times, and once I click the button that activates the API response again I get sentences[1] which also regenerates 6 times. It doesn't seem to give me an array of urls as I want.